# How can I print Views language-specific $field variable values inside a views template?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I am using Views with "Format Show:Content" instead of "... fields."

I have a multilingual website. In the filters section of Views I have Content: language = user's default language. However, Views refuses to honor this filter selection.

I am also using views-view-fields.tpl.php file to output the fields. currently it is calling, for example, $fields->content to output content.

How can I get Views in Show Content format to honor the language filter? I am familiar with needing to add the 'und' key to certain fields at times, but do I need to do that here? Should adding the filter in the view not be enough? If I do need to add the key where does it go?

If you want, you can see the error in the slideshow at http://goniseko.com

Answer (score 1):

Use dpm() to output $field in your template.

To make PHP not die with an out of memory error, use a static flag to ensure it only prints once.

```
static $_foo;
if (!$_foo) {
  dpm($field);
  $_foo = TRUE;
}
```